# Testing a Fragment class in isolation using Mockito

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, android-testing

Added `@VisibleForTesting` and protected. My test can now this method:

```
   @VisibleForTesting
    protected void setupDataBinding(List<Recipe> recipeList) {
        recipeAdapter = new RecipeAdapter(recipeList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        rvRecipeList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        rvRecipeList.setAdapter(recipeAdapter);
    }
```

Updated the test case using spy object: However, the real setupDataBinding(recipe) is getting called even when I created a mock of he spy that will get called. Maybe I am doing this wrong.

```
@Test
public void testShouldGetAllRecipes() {
    RecipeListView spy = Mockito.spy(fragment);
    doNothing().when(spy).setupDataBinding(recipe);

    fragment.displayRecipeData(recipe);

    verify(recipeItemClickListener, times(1)).onRecipeItemClick();
}
```

I am trying to test the methods in my `Fragment` class as below. However, I am trying to mock out the methods to verify that the methods are called the correct number of times. However, the problem is I have a `private` method `setupDataBinding(...)` that setups on the `RecyclerView` that is called from `displayRecipeData(...)`. I want to mock these calls as I don't want to call the real object on the `RecyclerView`. I just want to verify that `setupDataBinding(...)` gets called.

I have tried using spy and `VisibleForTesting`, but still not sure how to do this.

I am trying to test the Fragment in isolation.

```
public class RecipeListView
        extends MvpFragment<RecipeListViewContract, RecipeListPresenterImp>
        implements RecipeListViewContract {

    @VisibleForTesting
    private void setupDataBinding(List<Recipe> recipeList) {
        recipeAdapter = new RecipeAdapter(recipeList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        rvRecipeList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        rvRecipeList.setAdapter(recipeAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void displayRecipeData(List<Recipe> recipeList) {
        /* Verify this get called only once */
        setupDataBinding(recipeList);

        recipeItemListener.onRecipeItem();
    }
}
```

This is how I am testing. I have added the `VisibleForTesting` thinking I could help. And I have tried using the spy.

```
public class RecipeListViewTest {
    private RecipeListView fragment;
    @Mock RecipeListPresenterContract presenter;
    @Mock RecipeItemListener recipeItemListener;
    @Mock List<Recipe> recipe;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(RecipeListViewTest.this);
        fragment = RecipeListView.newInstance();
    }

    @Test
    public void testShouldGetAllRecipes() {
        fragment.displayRecipeData(recipe);
        RecipeListView spy = Mockito.spy(fragment);

        verify(recipeItemListener, times(1)).onRecipeItem();
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to test the above in isolation?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Adding `@VisibleForTesting` is not enough. You have to also change the access modifier for `setupDataBinding(...)` to protected, package-private or public.

Comment: @liminal I have updated my question with my latest attemps. I am failing to prevent the real method from bing called even though I created a spy object of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to prevent real method being called use: `Mockito.doNothing().when(spy).onRecipeItem();`

here you have minimum sample how to use it:

```
public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void testSpyObject() throws Exception {
        SpyTestObject spyTestObject = new SpyTestObject();
        SpyTestObject spy = Mockito.spy(spyTestObject);

        Mockito.doNothing().when(spy).methodB();

        spy.methodA();
        Mockito.verify(spy).methodB();
    }

    public class SpyTestObject {

        public void methodA() {
            methodB();
        }
        public void methodB() {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 3):

> I want to mock these calls as I don't want to call the real object on the `RecyclerView`. I just want to verify, that `setupDataBinding()` gets called.

You haven't created enough seams in order to perform that.

What if you declare a contract, which describes how the "setup data binding" will occur? In other words, what if you create an interface with method `void setupDataBinding(...)`? Then `RecipeListView` will hold an instance of that interface as a dependency. Thus, `RecipeListView` won't ever know how exactly this setup will take place: one thing it knows - the dependency he holds has "signed the contract" and took the responsibility to perform the job.

Normally, you would pass that dependency via constructor, but because `Fragment`
 [is a specific case](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#Fragment()), you can acquire dependencies in [`onAttach()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.content.Context)):

```
interface Setupper {
    void setupDataBinding(List<Recipe> recipes, ...);
}

class RecipeListView extends ... {

    Setupper setupper;

    @Override public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        // Better let the Dependency Injection tool (e.g. Dagger) provide the `Setupper`
        // Or initialize it here (which is not recommended)
        Setupper temp = ...
        initSetupper(temp);
    }

    void initSetupper(Setupper setupper) {
        this.setupper = setupper;
    }

    @Override
    public void displayRecipeData(List<Recipe> recipes) {
        // `RecipeListView` doesn't know what exactly `Setupper` does
        // it just delegates the work
        setupper.setupDataBinding(recipes, ...);

        recipeItemListener.onRecipeItem();
    }
}
```

What does this give to you? Now you have a **seam**. Now you are **not** dependent on implementation, you are dependent on a contract.

```
public class RecipeListViewTest {

    @Mock Setupper setupper;
    List<Recipe> recipe = ...; // initialize, no need to mock it
    ...

    private RecipeListView fragment;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        fragment = new RecipeListView();
        fragment.initSetupper(setupper);
    }

    @Test
    public void testShouldGetAllRecipes() {
        fragment.displayRecipeData(recipes);

        // You do not care what happens behind this call
        // The only thing you care - is to test whether is has been executed
        verify(setupper).setupDataBinding(recipe, ...);
        // verify(..) is the same as verify(.., times(1))
    }
}
```

I would strongly advice [Misko Hevery](https://twitter.com/mhevery?lang=en)'s ["Writing Testable Code"](http://misko.hevery.com/attachments/Guide-Writing%20Testable%20Code.pdf) book, which illustrates all the techniques with examples and in concise manner (38 pages).

Answer (score 1):

There is a common rule of thumb saying: **It's much better to test against what the unit does rather than how it does it.**

Taking this into account ask yourself a question - **why would I mock `setupDataBinding` method in the first place**? It doesn't make any external calls, it only changes the state of the object. So a better way to test this code is by checking whether it changes the state in a correct way:

```
@Test
public void testShouldGetAllRecipes() {
     fragment.displayRecipeData(recipeList);

     // Verifies whether RecipeAdapter has been initialized correctly
     RecipeAdapter recipeAdapter = fragment.getRecipeAdapter();
     assertNotNull(recipeAdapter);
     assertSame(recipeList, recipeAdapter.getRecipeList());

     // Verifies whethr RvRecipeList has been initialized correctly 
     RvRecipeList rvRecipeList = fragment.getRvRecipeList();
     assertNotNull(rvRecipeList);
     assertNotNull(rvRecipeList.getLayoutManager());
     assertSame(fragment.getRecipeAdapter(), rvRecipeList.getAdapter());
}
```

This may require adding several getters/setters to make the whole thing a bit more testable.

Comment: Misko Hevery: "Usually, the @VisibleForTesting annotation is a smell that the class was not written to be 
easily tested. And even though it will let you set the list of calls, it is only a hack to get around 
the root problem."

Comment: Yeah I agree. Well, then getters and setters shold be enough. I have updated my answer.